# Miniconda doesn't activate

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

I am working on a remote machine for my internship and ran into the following problem.
I ran `conda install -c huggingface -c conda-forge datasets`, which ended up taking ages (and for some reason downloaded a lot of useless packages) and seemingly got stuck, so I ctrl-c'ed the process. From there on, running `source ./miniconda3/bin/activate` would take upwards of 20 minutes. I tried deleting the entire folder `./miniconda3` and re-installing it from the shell file -- that didn't help.

I interact with conda using VSCode with Python and Jupyter Notebook extensions installed. I re-installed these extensions too out of despair, it also didn't fix the issue. I cannot run any cells in Jupyter, because activating the virtual environement times out. Is there something so that conda activation takes 1-2 seconds like it used to?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will fix it for you, but you could try making sure that you full uninstall miniconda before you re-install it. It makes changes to bashrc and has some other hidden folders. The vscode extension isn't going to be able to handle a 20 minute start up wait, so you'll need to resolve that issue first.

https://zditect.com/guide/python/uninstall-miniconda.html

Also I'm not sure that you should be calling source on the activation function of miniconda. At least for me, when using miniconda you should end up with `conda` on your terminal path. Then you just use `conda activate` to activate the environment you are working with.